# DJANGO: About linkinf wto tables with ForeignKey

Tags: django

Hello all and thanks for all the DAILY support, really.
Now, something I swear can not find answred in between many examples and related topics:

I have a **VEHICLES** model, and a **TIRES** model. Both will be linked by a field, PLATE;

```
class Vehicles(models.Model):
    Plate= models.CharField(max_length=10) 
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Vendor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.matricula  

class Tires(models.Model):
    Plate = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, default=0, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT) # --- tires would be placed in an exisiting vehicle (plate), or , if not in use, "Tires.Plate=0"
    Number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

What I need these two allow me to do, an what they really do or do not:

- Adding records to Vehicles.................YES
- Adding tires with predefined Plate numbers in a dropdown menu, from
  Vehicles.Plates....................YES, CHECK
- Adding tires with Plate number = 0, indicating the tire is not in use by any
  vehicle.......NO, NOT CHECKED; the menu offers ***only the exisiting***
  plates in "Vehicles.Plate": Even if I tried adding DEFAULT value.
- Deleting registers from TIRES.........CHECK
- Deleting registers from
  VEHICLES.......NOT CHECKED; doing so, instead of making the
  corresponding Tires.Plate default to 0, as I would have expected from
  `"...ForeignKey(Vehicle, default=0, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)"`, I
  get a ***"FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"*** error.

So indeed by removing the vehicle i'm causing the error of integrity - I've read definitions and logic of foreignkey, 1ary keys, sorry but, really, no example or tutorial I have read outlines this speciic case of use.

Can you give me an idea, ow there to look into it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `null` instead of `0` for the foreign key's default if it does not need to have a value

```
Plate = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Iain Shelvington that totally works thanks, now I will carefully meditate on that to get the clear picture. Thank you very much.